# How to use a scope to show all items above average for a particular attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to create a scope to show items with a `interest` greater than the the average of `interest` for the `company` they belong to. There is one model with products in it. Each product has the attributes of:

- `name`
- `interest`
- `company`

I can calculate the average of `interest` of each `company` with the code below:

```
def self.average_interest(company)
     where(company: company).average(:interest)
end
```

Then I am able to check the percentage difference between the item's `interest`, and the average for the `company` that it belongs to with this code:

```
def average_change_interest
     (self.interest - self.class.average_interest(self.company)) / self.class.average_interest(self.company) * 100
    end
```

I would now like a scope that only shows items whose `interest` is above the average for the `company` it belongs to.

This scope shows items with an `interest` greater than the average of `interest` of all items, but I would like for it to only show items whose interest is greater than the average of `interest` for the `company` they belong to.

```
scope :upward_trending, -> { where( "interest > ?", average(:interest)) }
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Thanks guys

Comment: Hey @Jordan thanks for the edit. I've also updated the content of the question, would be awesome if you could have a look, thanks mate.